# How to send message out Using Send mediator in wso2esb-4.8.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using wso2esb-4.8.1,
I wish to send my message out after that want to do auditing my message is going out and getting audit also when i use callout mediator Url option of I use send mediator URI Its not working.
sample proxy and sequence is

```
 <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Test_Proxy" transports="https http" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
        <description/>
        <target>
            <inSequence onError="FaultSeq">
                <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                <log>
                <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" name="ProxyInRequest" 
                expression="/soapenv:Envelope"/>
                </log>
                 <xquery key="ProxyRequestTransformation">
            <variable xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="Operation" expression="//Operation/text()" type="STRING"/>
            <variable xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="ServiceNameSpace" expression="//ServiceNameSpace/text()" type="STRING"/>
            <variable name="Payload" type="DOCUMENT_ELEMENT"/>
            <variable xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="ServiceName" expression="//Service/text()" type="STRING"/>
        </xquery>

           <send>
                    <endpoint>
                        <address uri="http://localhost:8081/middleware/services/test1" format="soap11"/>
                    </endpoint>
                </send>
            </inSequence>
            <outSequence onError="FaultSeq">
                <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
                    <property action="set" name="RESPONSE" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
                <send/>
                <sequence key="AuditSeq"/>
            </outSequence>
        </target>
        <publishWSDL key="EaiEnvelope"/>
</proxy>
```

and sequnce is like this

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="AuditSeq"> <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="RESULT_CODE" expression="get-property('ResultCode')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="RESULT_MESSAGE" expression="get-property('ResultMessage')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="REFERENCE_ID" expression="get-property('ReferenceID')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="FAULT_DETAILS" expression="concat(get-property('ERROR_CODE'),get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE'))" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <open:processRequest xmlns:open="http://www.openuri.org/">
                        <aud:Auditor xmlns:aud="http://jhm.kkk.fff/Auditor">
                            <aud:Request>
                                <aud:Operation_Name>processRequest</aud:Operation_Name>
                                <aud:Auditor_InputData>
                                    <aud:Result_Code>$1</aud:Result_Code>
                                    <aud:Result_Message>$2</aud:Result_Message>
                                    <aud:Reference_Id>$3</aud:Reference_Id>
                                    </aud:Auditor_InputData>
                            </aud:Request>
                        </aud:Auditor>
                    </open:processRequest>
                </format>
                <args>

                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('RESULT_CODE')"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('RESULT_MESSAGE')"/>
                     <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('REFERENCE_ID')"/>
                     </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <header name="Action" scope="default" value="http://www.openuri.org/processRequest"/>
           <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address uri="http://localhost:8081/middleware/services/AuditService" format="soap11"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </sequence>
```

If I use send mediator configuration its not getting called .Where as callout mediator is working fine with URL option and again its working with addressendpoint,

```
    if i use below properties its working fine




<callout serviceURL="http:///localhost:8081/middleware/services/AuditService">
                <source type="envelope"/>
                <target key="IsThisResponse"/>
            </callout>
```

I used this properties I am getting WSAction and soapAction coming NULL

```
 < header name="Action" scope="default" value="urn:http://www.openuri.org/processRequest"/>
            <header action="remove" name="To"/>
    <property action="set" name="RESPONSE" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
<property name="target.endpoint" value="AuditEndpoint"/>  
       <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>  
       <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3398 please see this for more reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you must change the **outSequence** in your proxy :

- you should clone the response message with **clone** mediator
- in the first target, you send back the reponse to the client with `<send/>`
- in the second target, you call your AuditSeq with `<sequence key="AuditSeq"/>`

Second thing, I can't find **OUT_ONLY** property set to true, so, your audit service at `http://localhost:8081/middleware/services/AuditService` should send you back a response and you must configure your send mediator to handle this response (you don't want the outSeuqence from your proxy to be call again) => You must change your AuditSeq adding an xml attribut **receive** to the send mediator :

```
<send receive="AuditServiceResponse">
  <endpoint>
    <address uri="http://localhost:8081/middleware/services/AuditService" format="soap11"/>
  </endpoint>
</send>
```

where **AuditServiceResponse** is a sequence (you can log or drop the response or whatever you want)

So, you're proxy's outSequence should become :

```
<outSequence onError="FaultSeq">
    <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
    <clone>
        <target>
            <sequence>
                <send/>
            </sequence>
        </target>
        <target>
            <sequence>
                <sequence key="AuditSeq"/>
            </sequence>
        </target>
    </clone>
</outSequence>
```

You're sequence AuditSeq should become :

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="AuditSeq">
    <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <property name="RESULT_CODE" expression="get-property('ResultCode')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <property name="RESULT_MESSAGE" expression="get-property('ResultMessage')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <property name="REFERENCE_ID" expression="get-property('ReferenceID')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <property name="FAULT_DETAILS" expression="concat(get-property('ERROR_CODE'),get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE'))" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
            <open:processRequest xmlns:open="http://www.openuri.org/">
                <aud:Auditor xmlns:aud="http://jhm.kkk.fff/Auditor">
                    <aud:Request>
                        <aud:Operation_Name>processRequest</aud:Operation_Name>
                        <aud:Auditor_InputData>
                            <aud:Result_Code>$1</aud:Result_Code>
                            <aud:Result_Message>$2</aud:Result_Message>
                            <aud:Reference_Id>$3</aud:Reference_Id>
                        </aud:Auditor_InputData>
                    </aud:Request>
                </aud:Auditor>
            </open:processRequest>
        </format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('RESULT_CODE')"/>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('RESULT_MESSAGE')"/>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('REFERENCE_ID')"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <header name="Action" scope="default" value="http://www.openuri.org/processRequest"/>
    <send receive="AuditServiceResponse">
        <endpoint>
            <address uri="http://localhost:8081/middleware/services/AuditService" format="soap11"/>
        </endpoint>
    </send>
</sequence>
```

And here come a sample AuditServiceResponse sequence :

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="AuditServiceResponse">
   <log level="full"/>
   <drop/>
</sequence>
```

Comment: I have used clone with clone I am getting response back to client as per ur guidence but audit service is keep on running I have used drop mediator also it even though its inserting unlimitedly.I m unable to stop it.

Comment: I've updated my response : have a look and verify your definitions. If you add a "receive" sequence to the 'send' mediator used to invoke your AuditService, it shouldn't be invoked indefinitely. If it's still the case, add logs to determine which sequences are replayed